# Invalidate Timer from Function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, viewdidload

I have an app written in `Swift` with an `NSTimer` declared in the `viewDidLoad`; the timer runs a function once every second.

Here's the code inside my `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let checkStateTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "callCheckState:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Currently, I have another function which is called which I want to pause the timer. It should, I believe, use:

```
checkStateTimer.invalidate()
```

However, because the timer is in the `viewDidLoad` and not the function or declared earlier, the function cannot access the `checkStateTimer`.

Trouble is, that I can't declare the timer outside the `viewDidLoad` (i.e just in the class) because it results in an error.

So, my question is, how do I get the view so that it will start the timer on `viewDidLoad`, but be able to pause the timer when the function runs. How is the best way of doing this so that it can stop the timer?

Comment: Create a function which toggles the timer on/off state, Call function from viewdidload and later on.

Comment: invalidate() doesn't pause the function it reset it

Comment: *"I can't declare the timer outside the viewDidLoad ... "* of course you can. *"... because it results in an error."* what error?

Comment: Thanks for your posts guys. Lamour, for me resetting it is just as good as pausing it for what I want to use it for. Martin R, ignore what I said, for some reason it didn't work when I tried it before posting this, but it does now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your timer as a class variable:

```
var checkStateTimer: NSTimer!
```

And then set it in viewDidLoad():

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    checkStateTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "callCheckState:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Then in your function invalidate the timer:

```
func someFunction() {
    checkStateTimer.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: Weirdly, I tried this before posting this and it didn't stop the timer, but for some reason now it does! Thanks for your help!